# how to remove error of update query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I write doctrine update query in symfony but it always takes last data and put it in all the fields, here is my code:

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $response = new Response();

            for($i=0; $i<$sectioncounter; $i++){
             $sectionname = $_POST['sectionName'.$i];
             $description=$_POST['description'.$i];
              $query = $em->createQuery("Update ProposalsProposalsBundle:Sections s  set s.sectionName='".$sectionname."',s.description='".$description."',s.updatedDatetime='".$date."' where s.proposalID='".$proposalid."'");    
             $ids = $query->getResult();
            }
        return $response;
        }
```

My `sectioncounter=2` but when I check in database `$description1,$sectionname1` values overwrite `$sectionname0` and description0, how to remove this error?
I want update query to run `sectioncounter` times, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you change the value of $proposalid? If you dont change this you are executing this query many times afecting the same row

Comment: my $proposalid=1,but in section table 2 rows inserted of this id

Comment: Do you have two rows with the same id? If so, the last update overwrite every row fields (those you change in your query) with this proposalId.